# Reading three Files in parallel and writing the contents in sequentially in other file using Multi threading without join method

Tags: java, multithreading

I got a question in my last interview, its all about multithreading, interviewer asked me to write a program, to write the contents of three files(F1,F2,F3) in to a new File F4, using multithreading , first thread should read the first file and second thread should read second file, so the File F4 should contain F1's contents in first then F2's contents after that etc. I tried to give my best shot, but i couldn't get a way to ensure that the threads are writing the file in order that is first thread writes the first file content, then second thread and on.

One strange condition was that i'm not supposed to use join method.

I wrote the below program, but couldn't get the writing file logic to make sure contents are in order, please help me in this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;


public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    final static String FILE_NAME1 = "C:\\Temp\\input1.txt";
    final static String FILE_NAME2 = "C:\\Temp\\input2.txt";
    final static String FILE_NAME3 = "C:\\Temp\\input3.txt";
    final static String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Temp\\output.txt";
    final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    List<String> readTextFile1;
    List<String> readTextFile2;
    List<String> readTextFile3;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
        if(t.getName().equals("t1"))
        {
            System.out.println("Started"+ t.getName());
            try {
                readTextFile1 = readTextFile(FILE_NAME1);

                writeTextFile(readTextFile1,OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Ended"+ t.getName());
        }
        if(t.getName().equals("t2"))
        {
            System.out.println("Started"+ t.getName());
                try {
                    readTextFile2 = readTextFile(FILE_NAME2);

                    writeTextFile(readTextFile2,OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Ended"+ t.getName());

        }
        if(t.getName().equals("t3"))
        {
            System.out.println("Started"+ t.getName());

            try {
                readTextFile3 = readTextFile(FILE_NAME3);

                writeTextFile(readTextFile3,OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            } catch (IOException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Ended"+ t.getName());
        }


    }


    List<String> readTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        return Files.readAllLines(path, ENCODING);
    }

    void writeTextFile(List<String> strLines, String fileName) throws IOException {
        synchronized (fileName) {
              Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
              Files.write(path, strLines, ENCODING,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadTest tt1=new ThreadTest();
        ThreadTest tt2=new ThreadTest();
        ThreadTest tt3=new ThreadTest();
        Thread t1=new Thread(tt1, "t1");
        Thread t2=new Thread(tt2, "t2");
        Thread t3=new Thread(tt3, "t3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have each thread read the file contents, store it, but not write it. Then you could have your main thread wait until those three threads are done using wait and notify statements and then `get()` the content. Leave the writing to the main thread where it doesn't have to worry about concurrency.

Comment: If the files are really large and you get to read from more than 3 I would generalize it by passing a countDownLatch to each thread except the last and then just polling on each queue passed to each thread until we find a null element (of your choosing), at witch point i would remove the queue from the collection (the reading from that file is done and the latch for the next one has been released)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Semaphore is kind of like using a join-method but without calling the join-method. And it can be replaced with a volatile and a `while` loop like @anirban describes (see the lines commented out below):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Read3Write1 implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService tp = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Read3Write1[] readers = new Read3Write1[3];
    // start threads in reverse order to show it does not matter to end-result.
    for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--) {
        tp.execute(readers[i] = new Read3Write1("FileName dummy " + i + System.getProperty("line.separator")));
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            bout.write(readers[i].getFileContents());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new String(bout.toByteArray()));
    tp.shutdownNow();
}

private final String fileName;
private final Semaphore done = new Semaphore(0);
// private volatile boolean done;
private volatile byte[] fileContents;

public Read3Write1(String fileName) {
    super();
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public byte[] getFileContents() {

    try {
        done.acquire();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    // while (!done) { Thread.yield(); }
    return fileContents; 
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        fileContents = readFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        done.release();
        // done = true;
    }
}

private byte[] readFile() {
    return fileName.getBytes();
}

}
```

A use case for this technique is when many files need to be read from different network drives mounted over a slow and unstable network. Reading files 1 by 1 could take N-times more time than reading all files at the same time and storing (a copy of) the contents to (a fast) local disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `volatile` sharing resource like a `int` variable and let first thread start writing, once done change the `int` resource to 2 so that 2nd thread can start writing. once done, change the volatile variable value to 3. So third thread can start.

Each thread should have a `while()` loop, continuously trying to write until a specific value is set in shared volatile variable.